# listings' otherkeywords={if} also identifies 'shift' as a keyword

Tags: listings

I am trying to paste Isabelle code into a LaTeX document using the listings package.  The nearest `language=` options seem to be `ML` and `Haskell`.

Some of the code contains blocks delineated by quotation marks (`"..."`) within which there are keywords.

Specifying `language=ML` or `language=Haskell` does not embolden keywords within the `"..."` blocks (e.g. `" ... if ... "`).

On the other hand, setting `otherkeywords={if}` does embolden keywords within quotation blocks, but also picks up variable names like `shift`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=ML,
        otherkeywords={if,then,else,return,"}
        }

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    "if foo then bar * shift"
   \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

First the sh`if`t-problem:

This is because, according to the [docs](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)

> [Otherkeywords] [d]efines keywords that contain other characters, or start with digits. Each
>   given ‘keyword’ is printed in keyword style, but without changing the ‘letter’,
>   ‘digit’ and ‘other’ status of the characters. This is designed to define keywords like =>, ->, -->, --, ::, and so on.

I believe that `morekeywords` might be what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{%
morekeywords={if,then,else,return},
keywordstyle=\color{red}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    "if foo then bar * shift"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This should fix the "if" being highlighted within "shift".

Now, for the enclosed quotes. Listings recognizes this as a string, which isn't that odd considering that `"..."` defined as string-blocks in the `ML`-language (see bottom code snippet).

You could add `deletestring=[d]",` to the `\lstset`, to make it not recognize `"` as strings.

Then this might be what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{%
language=ML,
morekeywords={if,then,else,return},
deletestring=[d]",
keywordstyle=\color{red}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    "if foo then bar * shift"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

You might also find this useful:
This is the definition of the listings ML-language (from `lstlang2.sty`):

```
%%
%% ML definition (c) 1999 Torben Hoffmann
%%
\lst@definelanguage{ML}%
  {morekeywords={abstype,and,andalso,as,case,do,datatype,else,end,%
       eqtype,exception,fn,fun,functor,handle,if,in,include,infix,%
       infixr,let,local,nonfix,of,op,open,orelse,raise,rec,sharing,sig,%
       signature,struct,structure,then,type,val,with,withtype,while},%
   sensitive,%
   morecomment=[n]{(*}{*)},%
   morestring=[d]"%
  }[keywords,comments,strings]%
```