# Adding keyword to a listing that matches exact instances

Tags: listings, algorithms, keywords

I want to add more keywords to a listing, however, I only want to match the exact instances of that new keyword, as the keyword sometimes happened to occur as part of normal words and it gets colored wrongly:

An example:

```
otherkeywords={in,out,inout},
morekeywords={in,out,inout}
```

I get something  like this,

[image]

**Edit (possible answer, not for my case):**
I am using a separate file for each listing in my tex document, also I have a string line of code, so the suggested method at the commit works only if you write the code directly inside the tex document and you don't use a string in your code. so possible answer for others is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431927/listings-otherkeywords-if-also-identifies-shift-as-a-keyword)

Comment: this works only for code written directly within the same document, and if the code doesn't have a string line, but I am using **C/C++** with some string, and use separate **.c** files for my code (as I have large code), so this is not working for me

Comment: I just tried `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
morekeywords={in,out,inout},
keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{examplekeywords.c}
Inline: \lstinline{calculate_binary_weights(*net); in != binary;}
\end{document}` and it works fine (with the contents of the `examplekeywords.c` file the same as the inline code). Both for the code from the file and the inline code the word _in_ is printed in blue but the string _in_ inside _binary_ is black.

Comment: Note that the difference with your code is that `otherkeywords` is not used here, as explained in the duplicate question.

Comment: It is not working because I am using [language=C]

Comment: I just tried `\lstset{language=C,
morekeywords={in,out,inout},
keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}` and it still works.

Comment: If you can show a small but complete example document (something similar to my comment above, so including `\documentclass` and such) where it does not work then it will be easier to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: OK it works now,  it works with your example, in addition to your answer I hat to add an extra thing to make **#pragma** workers in C/C++, I had to make this `otherkeywords={pragma, \#}`  , many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is from the comments above with some modification which are:

1. Hilight the `#pragma` keyword in a C/C++ code
2. New keywords are not highlighted inside a string

---

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\lstset{
    language=C,
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle={\color{red}},
    keywordstyle={\color{blue}}, 
    otherkeywords={pragma, \#},
    morekeywords={in,out,inout,omp}
 }
\begin{document} 
\lstinputlisting{a.c} 
Inline: \lstinline{calculate_binary_weights(*net); in != binary;} 
\end{document}
```

The output would be:

> [image]